# Where can I find the quotes from the loading screens?

Tags: shogun-2-total-war

The quotes in Shogun 2 are amazing. But the loading screen loads so fast. Does anybody know where to get the quotes they show there?

Comment: Get a slower computer! In all seriousness though, it's probably in an archive or compiled into a binary somewhere, as looking through the Empire folders, I can't find the quotes, while iirc, they were just a text file in RTW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[here](http://www.mediafire.com/?2h8e8p794zm3078) are all the quotes in .txt format, if anyone is interested.

Comment: mediafire? There's no way I bother to download a simple txt with a site like that, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @Loo The problem is that we can't host them directly :/

Answer (score 7):

Yay i found them!

For the english version they are in:

```
<game folder>/data/data.pack
Inside the file go /db/quotes_tables/quotes
```

For the translated version of the game (russian in my example) they are in:

```
<game folder>/data/local_ru.pack
Inside the file go /text/localisation.loc 
and there look for tags starting with "quotes_quote_onscreen_".
```

To open a .pack file use [this program](http://www.twcenter.net/forums/showthread.php?t=433370)